# How to create factory boy with several child

Tags: python, django

I have two [Django models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/models/) like:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    country_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)

class Resident(models.Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    age = models.PositiveSmallInteger()
```

and I want to [Factory Boy](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/orms.html) create a `Country` with two children which have different attribute(s).

For example, `somefactory.create()` creates `FooCountry` and `FooCountry` has two residents:

```
name=Paul, country=foo, age=33
name=Jamse, country=foo, age=34
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First write down `CountryFactory` and `ResidentFactory` (as described in FactoryBoy documentation). Then write your function:

```
def create_country_with_residents():
    country = CountryFactory.create()
    ResidentFactory.create(country=country, name=Paul, age=33)
    ResidentFactory.create(country=country, name=James, age=34)
    return country
```